# Printing text below existing text in csv iteratively in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Iam printing a string to a csv file. Is there a way to add another string below the pre-exisiting text in the csv file iteratively in bash?

For example, let´s say my current csv file looks like this

```
12, hello, english
13, hola, espanol
14, hat tip!, british
```

The next iteration of the string should append text below the above text so it looks like below and so on.

```
12, hello, english
13, hola, espanol
14, hat tip!, british
15, namaste, hindi 
16, hallo, german
```

Comment: Kindly try to add your efforts too in your post which you have made to solve your problem(s) as we all are here to learn. Cheers, keep learning and keep sharing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bash redirection operator `>>` appends to the end of the output file.

```
printf '%i,%s,%s\n' \
    15 "namaste" "hindi" \
    16 "hallo" "german" >>file.csv
```

Your question sounds vaguely like you want to do this from inside a loop of some sort. Notice how

```
while condition; do
    something >>file
done
```

is remarkably less efficient than

```
while condition; do
    something
done >>file
```

because in the former case, the shell must reopen, seek to end of file, and close the file handle repeatedly inside the loop. (Well, the seek is done by the OS, but it's still not free.)

Comment: If you really genuinely want spaces after the commas, by all means add them back; but this seems like a mistake.

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** In you have bunch of strings to be concatenated to your Input_file's output then you could mention them in your `awk` command and then could use it like()by doing this you need not to hard code anything:

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=OFS=", ";
  num=split("namaste, hindi;hallo, german",array,";")
}
1;
END{
  val=$1;
  for(i=1;i<=num;i++){
    print ++val,array[i]}
}'  Input_file
```

---

---

Following `awk` may help here.

```
awk -v line1="15, namaste, hindi" -v line2="16, hallo, german" '1; END{print line1 ORS line2}'  Input_file
```

Solution 2nd: Using simple `cat` commands considering that your new lines are present in a new file. So it will be:

```
cat Input_file Input_file_with_new_lines
```

Above will only print them on console, in case you want to save that Input_file itself then append following in above code(s) too.

```
 > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Comment: DOWN VOTER, please mention the reason for down vote here?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "} {print}
     END   {print ++$1,"namaste, hindi"; print ++$1,"hallo, german"}' file
```

Output:

```
12, hello, english
13, hola, espanol
14, hat tip!, british
15, namaste, hindi
16, hallo, german
```

Comment: Hi Cyrus, 
Thanks for your reply. If the subsequent was to be referenced from a variable and then outputted to csv. would I write as below?

`awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=", "} {print}
     END   {print ++$1,"$secondstring"}' > output.csv`

Comment: This might help: `secondstring="foobar"; awk -v str="$secondstring" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} {print} END{print ++$1,str}' file`

Comment: the suffix "file" at the end is for outputting the text to the csv?

Comment: @KaushalKapoor, please EDIT your post with full information, adding your requirement in comments is not recommended, kindly do so.

Comment: `file` is in my example the name of the file from which `awk` reads the data.